# Sql azure blank database username and password missing

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I created a sql azure DB. I had 3 options as source:

- blank database
- sample
- backup

I selected blank. No username and password was asked. in the connection string there is a place holder for username and password. What should I give here?
And more over I am not able to connect to this DB from VS studio(asking username and password).

Edited Later: Actually I get to give user name and password when I create a server and not a DB. what I did above was creating a new db on an existing server and hence no username was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the credentials that you set up when configuring the hosting SQL Azure Server. If you want to use another account just for that database (recommended), you will need to login to the SQL Azure Server using the original credentials and follow this post:

**SCRIPT :**

**connect to Master and run below query:**

```
CREATE LOGIN blog WITH password='xxxxxxx'
GO

CREATE USER [blog] FOR LOGIN [blog] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

**Then Connect to Database of your choice and run below:**

```
CREATE USER [blog] FOR LOGIN [blog] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'blog';
GO
```

please see the below link for more details
http://kitsula.com/Article/How-to-create-custom-user-login-for-Azure-SQL-Database

Comment: I did not setup any credentials when configuring the hosting SQL Azure Server

Comment: Setting up an admin username/password is a requirement when creating the server - [link](http://imgur.com/Y7Z5ZQU)

Comment: ok I get it. I was using the same server. And when I created a new server I got the option to set password thanks.

Comment: @JustinPatten:please add relevant info from the links,i have edited it now

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Thanks for the edit. Will remember that in the future.